# Obtener información de un archivo XML de una URL y previa autenticación a través de POST

Tags: php, xml, post

Un saludo, no tengo mucho trabajando con PHP y buscando ejercicios para practicar, encontré esto en uno de los juegos con los que me entretengo y me plantee extrear esta información usando PHP.

[Ayuda para usar la API de Sokker](http://sokker.org/xmlinfo.php)

Intento seguir los pasos dejados en el enlace para obtener información de la página usando su api y consigo autenticarme usan el siguiente código

```
$url = "http://sokker.org/start.php?session=xml"; // The POST URL
$data = "ilogin=user&ipassword=password"; // The POST Data
$options = array(
    'http' => // The wrapper to be used
        array(
            'method' => 'POST', // Request Method
            // Request Headers Below
            'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $data
        )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
echo $result;
```

Ahora lo que no consigo es manipular la información de los documentos xml.
Un ejemplo sería este http://sokker.org/start.php?session=xml/team-29008.xml

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Saludos!! Puedes utilizar [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/es/class.simplexmlelement.php), de esta manera:

```
$response = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
```

Esta clase transforma el documento XML en un objeto de PHP para su manipulación.

Si tienes problemas con `$result` puedes utilizar [php://input](http://php.net/manual/es/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input), esto me sirvió a mi

```
$response = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```